# JavaScript drop down to display content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.group').hide();
     $('#selectMe').change(function () {
         $('.group').hide();
         $('#' +$(this).val()).show();
     })
 });


<html>
<label for="hi" title="hi">hi</label>
<select name="selectMe" id="selectMe">
<option>Select</option>
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>
<div id="option1" class="group">
<label for="Your State" title="Your State">Your State</label>
<select name="Your State" id="Your State">
<option>Select</option>
<option value="albama">Albama</option>
<option value="alaska">Alaska</option> 
<option value="arizona">Arizona</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="option2" class="group">xxxx</div>
<div id="option3" class="group">vvvv</div>
<div id="option4" class="group">dddd</div>
</html>
```

I have the code to display <kbd>Your state</kbd> drop down when user selects option1.

When he selects Arizona from <kbd>Your state</kbd> I need to display "Hi friends" at the bottom of two drop downs.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are after?

http://jsfiddle.net/tR2xU/

Comment: I just make changes to it but it is not working in my application do i need some more changes to it.

Comment: I have change the id for your select tag, as in the in fiddle example. as Your State with a space is not very friendly to use from js or css, was just easier. Sorry forgot to mention it :)